# Joomla 3.2 installation error: Table usergroups doesn't exist

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.2

I have a problem - after fresh installation of Joomla 3.2, I get the following error from the web-based interactive automatic installation script:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 11
>   SQL=CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `j32_usergroups` ( `id` int(10)
>   unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key', `parent_id`
>   int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Adjacency List Reference
>   Id', `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Nested set lft.', `rgt`
>   int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.', `title`
>   varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY
>   `idx_usergroup_parent_title_lookup` (`parent_id`,`title`), KEY
>   `idx_usergroup_title_lookup` (`title`), KEY
>   `idx_usergroup_adjacency_lookup` (`parent_id`), KEY
>   `idx_usergroup_nested_set_lookup` (`lft`,`rgt`) USING BTREE )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>
> Table 'mydb_8.j32_usergroups' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO
>   `j32_usergroups` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `title`) VALUES (1,
>   0, 1, 18, 'Public'), (2, 1, 8, 15, 'Registered'), (3, 2, 9, 14,
>   'Author'), (4, 3, 10, 13, 'Editor'), (5, 4, 11, 12, 'Publisher'), (6,
>   1, 4, 7, 'Manager'), (7, 6, 5, 6, 'Administrator'), (8, 1, 16, 17,
>   'Super Users'), (9, 1, 2, 3, 'Guest')

Seems that the installation script failed to create the table. Surprisingly, these problems were present in the version 1.x too (as I found by google). I haven't found any solution besides some hacking of the installation script. One of most used CMS must be installable in some cleaner way than this, I hope!!

My setup:

- database type: MySQLi
- host name: localhost
- table prefix: j32_

There are other tables in the db but no tables beginning with j32.

PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u7, MySQL 5.0.51a-24+lenny5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [Joomla Requirements](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html) for Joomla 3.x, you will see that the minimum MySQL version required is 5.1, and on your localhost, you're using 5.0.51a. So I would start by updating MySQL. Also ensure that you have InnoDB support as this is also required.

Comment: Innodb support there is... Thank you, I will try.